# Unity build and run not working with android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I created an Image tracker with Vuforia using unity and I am getting error messages when I try to "build and run". When I simply build I just have to uplod the APK in AndroidStudio and run it. But when I click build and run I get this error messages

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00234] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:96 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

And I researched this and tried
1. renaming my "Tools" folder in my SDK root and swapping with SDK 26.1.1(Didn't work)
2. Using an older version of JDK(Didn't work)
3.Reimport all(Didn't work)
4.Run as admin (Didn't work)

Any Ideas? I am using Unity 2018.3.4f1

Comment: You can just try creating a build and installing that on a virtual device instead, if build and run is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after successfully previously building and running to my android device. The issue was that I renamed a different project to have the same name, so it could match my Firebase project name. Renaming the apk to something different wasn't the issue, but the fact that I already had an apk on my device using the same project name was the issue.

Delete the old apk on your android device, and this could fix the issue.